# Group by en con Subconsultas Sql Server

Tags: sql-server

Quisiera solo 3 count solo las cantidades

```
select ( 
    select count(DISTINCT concat(U_codpro,U_codemp)) 
    from [PE_SBO_BSH_ELECTRODOMESTICOS_SAC].[dbo].[@A1A_RSPC] 
    where U_codpro = '201803EMP') as [a],
    ( 
      select count(DISTINCT concat(U_codpro,U_codemp)) 
      from [PE_SBO_BSH_ELECTRODOMESTICOS_SAC].[dbo].[@A1A_RSPC] 
      where U_codpro = '201803OBR') as [c] ,
    ( 
      select count(DISTINCT concat(U_codpro,U_codemp)) 
      from [PE_SBO_BSH_ELECTRODOMESTICOS_SAC].[dbo].[@A1A_RSPC] 
      where U_codpro = '201803LBSOBR'
) as [p]
 from [PE_SBO_BSH_ELECTRODOMESTICOS_SAC].[dbo].[@A1A_RSPC] a 
 where U_codpro like '201803%' 
 group by U_codemp/*1,2,3*/--[a],[c],[p]
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola Dannylo, por favor incluye el esquema de las tablas, y un poco de data de pruba y el resultado que quieres que tenga la respuesta. Así podremos entender mejor tu requerimiento. Además no coloques tu código como imágen sino como texto.

Comment: @CarlosMuñoz solo quisiera que muetre 1 fila con 3 columnas de las 3 subconsultas intente hacerle con allias o 1,2,3 pero me sigue botanto demasiadas filas por el u_codEmp que es el codigo del cliente algunas forma de que se agrupe en una fila GRacias

Comment: Como te menciono arriba, tu pregunta no se entiende, por favor completa mas información para poder ayudarte

Comment: Podrias mirar por favor el [tour] y tambien como preguntar?

Comment: Si pones el resultado como texto y no como imagen te vamos a poder ayudar mas. Como primera medida, te diria que tu query esta mal, ya que no tiene nada que ver la tabla donde haces el from, con las tres tablas sobre las cuales haces el subquery. Tal vez podrias mostrarnos un set reducido de datos y como quisieras el resultado para que podamos ayudarte mejor?

Answer (score 1):

Creo que esto es lo que buscas. Sin mas información de tu pregunta no puedo ayudarte más.

```
SELECT
    [201803EMP],
    [201803BR],
    [201803LBSOBR]
FROM
    (SELECT DISTINCT
        U_codpro,
        U_codemp
    FROM
        [PE_SBO_BSH_ELECTRODOMESTICOS_SAC].[dbo].[@A1A_RSPC]
    ) AS Datos
PIVOT
(
    COUNT(U_codemp)
    FOR U_codpro IN ([201803EMP], [201803BR], [201803LBSOBR])
) AS Resultado
```

Comment: Tienes toda la razón, @Dannylo Ramos solo debe tener en cuenta que si necesita agregar otro código de producto debe añadirlo en el select y en el for del pivot